# Cython set variable to named constant

Tags: cython, cythonize

I'm chasing my tail with what I suspect is a simple problem, but I can't seem to find any explanation for the observed behavior. Assume I have a constant in a C header file defined by:

```
#define FOOBAR 128
typedef uint32_t mytype_t;
```

I convert this in Cython by putting the following in the .pxd file:

```
cdef int _FOOBAR   "FOOBAR"
ctypedef uint32_t mytype_t
```

In my .pyx file, I have a declaration:

```
FOOBAR = _FOOBAR
```

followed later in a class definition:

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef mytype_t myvar
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.myvar = FOOBAR
            print("GOOD")
        except:
            print("BAD")
```

I then try to execute this with a simple program:

```
try:
    foo = MyClass()
except:
    print("FAILED TO CREATE CLASS")
```

Sadly, this errors out, but I don't get an error message - I just get the exception print output:

```
BAD
```

Any suggestions on root cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My apologies - in my desire to simplify the problem I apparently left out some critical info. The problem occurs when the variable isn't an integer but instead a defined fixed type. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. You can use Cython's verbatim code (http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code) to make it stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have finally tracked it down. The root cause issue is that `FOOBAR` in my code was actually set to `UINT32MAX`. Apparently, Cython/Python interprets that as a `-1` and Python then rejects setting a `uint32_t` variable equal to it. The solution is to define `FOOBAR` to be `0xffffffff` - apparently Python thinks that is a non-negative value and accepts it.